# Azure pipeline error "Git fetch failed with exit code: 128"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create a build pipeline in azure devops using this blog:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ci-cd-azure-databricks-using-devops-deepak-rajak.

I have created a service connection with the my repository. I am getting this error and I can't resolve it. I think it is picking the wrong URL.

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, this error means that the Git repository URL is wrong.

> I have created a service connection with the my repository.

You need to correct the repo URL from the service connection. Not sure which Git repository you are using.

However, please note that URL should not be the project URL (e.g `https://github.com/xxx/test`).

It should be something like this: `https://github.com/xxx/test.git`

Comment: @Pallavi Have you resolved the issue by changing the URL of the repository?

Answer (score -1):

Please control your permission settings in Version Control.

in Azure , project settings >> version control.
select repositories and look security for all git repositories.

"Project collection administrator"

Comment: Hello I have already done this setting but it is still not working, also my repository is not added as a repository in my azure project but rather as a service connection. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly. but I will try to get the same error with an example like you said.